# How to using ObjectMapper to map value of an json property to Object when my object have an contractor set this property is null

Tags: java, mapping

I am usng google DirectionsResul Object

And then I want to using Object mapper to mapping this json to DirectionsResul Object

```
{
  "geocoded_waypoints": [],
  "routes": [
    {
      "bounds": {},
      "legs": [
        {
          "distance": {
            "human_readable": "13 km",
            "in_meters": 13175
          },
          "duration": {
            "human_readable": "37 phút",
            "in_seconds": 2206
          },
          "steps": []
        }
      ],
      "overview_polyline": {
        "points": "aaaa"
      },
      "warnings": [],
      "waypoint_order": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Using this code

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

DirectionsResult result;
result = objectMapper.readValue(json, DirectionsResult.class.);
```

All is ok but overview_polyline can't mapping, the points value is null
and I see in the EncodedPolyline have a contractor like this

```
public EncodedPolyline() {
        this.points = null;
    }
```

So how can I mapping the points value to the DirectionsResul Object

Here is my result I got
[image: Result]

Here is all the code that can run

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.maps.model.DirectionsResult;
public void testGetDirections() throws NetworkException {
String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"geocoded_waypoints\": [],\n" +
                "  \"routes\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"bounds\": {\n" +
                "        \"northeast\": {\n" +
                "          \"lat\": 34.1358593,\n" +
                "          \"lng\": -117.922066\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        \"southwest\": {\n" +
                "          \"lat\": 33.815582,\n" +
                "          \"lng\": -118.3516983\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"legs\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "          \"distance\": {\n" +
                "            \"human_readable\": \"13 km\",\n" +
                "            \"in_meters\": 13175\n" +
                "          },\n" +
                "          \"duration\": {\n" +
                "            \"human_readable\": \"37 phút\",\n" +
                "            \"in_seconds\": 2206\n" +
                "          },\n" +
                "          \"steps\": [\n" +
                "            {\n" +
                "              \"distance\": {\n" +
                "                \"human_readable\": \"10 ft\",\n" +
                "                \"in_meters\": 3\n" +
                "              },\n" +
                "              \"duration\": {\n" +
                "                \"human_readable\": \"1 min\",\n" +
                "                \"in_seconds\": 0\n" +
                "              }\n" +
                "            }\n" +
                "          ]\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "      ],\n" +
                "      \"overview_polyline\": {\n" +
                "        \"points\": \"{ashdasda}\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"warnings\": [],\n" +
                "      \"waypoint_order\": []\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        DirectionsResult goongMapsDirectionResult;


        try {
            goongMapsDirectionResult = objectMapper.readValue(json, DirectionsResult.class.);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That should be fine, as the object mapper will set the values reflectively after the object has been created. Does this actually not work, or do you just think it might not? If it really doesn't work, please provide a complete example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: It's really doesn't work. 
[link](https://imgur.com/r7VwxUX)
This is my result I got

Comment: OK, please edit your question to include code we can run which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Yes. It is google. Here is the import code 
```
import com.google.maps.model.DirectionsResult;
```

Comment: Thanks for actually providing runnable code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no setter for `points` on `EncodedPolyline`.

One way to work around this is to use a `DeserializationProblemHandler`:

```
public class SO69242058 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                      "  \"geocoded_waypoints\": [],\n" +
                      "  \"routes\": [\n" +
                      "    {\n" +
                      "      \"bounds\": {\n" +
                      "        \"northeast\": {\n" +
                      "          \"lat\": 34.1358593,\n" +
                      "          \"lng\": -117.922066\n" +
                      "        },\n" +
                      "        \"southwest\": {\n" +
                      "          \"lat\": 33.815582,\n" +
                      "          \"lng\": -118.3516983\n" +
                      "        }\n" +
                      "      },\n" +
                      "      \"legs\": [\n" +
                      "        {\n" +
                      "          \"distance\": {\n" +
                      "            \"human_readable\": \"13 km\",\n" +
                      "            \"in_meters\": 13175\n" +
                      "          },\n" +
                      "          \"duration\": {\n" +
                      "            \"human_readable\": \"37 phút\",\n" +
                      "            \"in_seconds\": 2206\n" +
                      "          },\n" +
                      "          \"steps\": [\n" +
                      "            {\n" +
                      "              \"distance\": {\n" +
                      "                \"human_readable\": \"10 ft\",\n" +
                      "                \"in_meters\": 3\n" +
                      "              },\n" +
                      "              \"duration\": {\n" +
                      "                \"human_readable\": \"1 min\",\n" +
                      "                \"in_seconds\": 0\n" +
                      "              }\n" +
                      "            }\n" +
                      "          ]\n" +
                      "        }\n" +
                      "      ],\n" +
                      "      \"overview_polyline\": {\n" +
                      "        \"points\": \"{ashdasda}\"\n" +
                      "      },\n" +
                      "      \"warnings\": [],\n" +
                      "      \"waypoint_order\": []\n" +
                      "    }\n" +
                      "  ]\n" +
                      "}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
        //objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        objectMapper.addHandler(new DeserializationProblemHandler() {

            @Override
            public boolean handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext ctxt, JsonParser p,
                                                 JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer, Object beanOrClass,
                                                 String propertyName) throws IOException {
                EncodedPolyline encodedPolyline = (EncodedPolyline)beanOrClass;
                try {
                    Field f = EncodedPolyline.class.getDeclaredField("points");
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    f.set(encodedPolyline, p.readValueAs(String.class));
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        DirectionsResult goongMapsDirectionResult;

        goongMapsDirectionResult = objectMapper.readValue(json, DirectionsResult.class);
    }
}
```

I've removed `objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)` so that the error occurs when Jackson tries to set `points`. Then we set it reflectively.